# increase rate limit of twitter 

Tags: api, twitter, tweets, posting

I have web product (third party) that’s built, establishes growth of approx 100k users and all have authenticated their twitter account. But the twitter is limited me to 350 req/h.

Is there a way to apply for a higher limit for API calls, or what will be the best solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The rates have changed since this question was posted. In `OAuth v1.1` the rate limits are measured per 15 mins. Depending what you are calling the limits are 15, 30, 180 (for `user_timeline` which is what most people want) and 300 per 15 min chunk.

See [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) table for the limits

You can find how many of each call you have left and when the limit is reset by using `application/rate_limit_status`.